# Get DOM element's in-flow position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, transform

```js
alert("Wrong (red): " + document.getElementById("target").getBoundingClientRect().top);
alert("Correct (blue): " + document.getElementById("wrapper").getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

```css
#target {
  transform: translate(20px, -20px) rotateZ(20deg);
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#wrapper {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
Text
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="target">
  </div>
</div>
further text
```

In the example above, the blue square has the exact position, the red one *would* have, if it had no `transform`. It has also exactly the space and position that the red square *consumes*, as an in-flow element. The position I want to get in JavaScript is the position of the blue square. My only problem is, that in my original code, there is no `#wrapper` and I am not able to create one. So how do I get the in-flow position of an element that might or might not be on that position (due to `transform`, `position: relative;` or others - if there are)?

Plain JS or jQuery solutions are both welcome. But I search for a rather simple/short solution, not some 50+ lines monster.

My attempts:

- `jQuery('#target').offset()`: Takes `transform` into account (returns some negative number in the above example).
- `document.getElementById('target').getBoundingClientRect()`: Same as jQuery's `offset`
- `jQuery('#target').position()` with traversing through `offsetParent`: *Might* currently work, but jQuery's behavior in this regard is considered a **bug** or at least subject to coming changes, according to [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1765) site (if I interpret that site correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebKitCSSMatrix`

```
  var node = document.getElementById("target");
  var curTransform = new   WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(node).webkitTransform);
  console.log(node.offsetLeft + curTransform.m41); //real offset left
  console.log(node.offsetTop + curTransform.m42); //real offset top
```

## Browser Compatibility :

- Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015128/747579) to know how to handle browsers that isn't support `WebKitCSSMatrix`

Comment: Thanks for your time. If you want the check mark, please read the question again, carefully, and make this an actual _answer_ to it. Yes, this is a _part of a hint_ to _some_ answer but StackOverflow was imho not designed to be a guessing game but instead a pool of solutions for problems. And my problem (getting the in-flow position of an element) should be rather common. Btw. I think (or hope) that this is not the best way of achieving the goal though, because it is hacky (does not consider all eventualities).